# MongoDB find document by date range - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I want to find a specific document via a date range (`beginDate` should be greater or equals - and `closeDate` should be lesser or equals the current date).
The document looks like this:

```
{ "beginDate" : ISODate("2014-11-03T23:00:00Z"), 
  "closeDate" : ISODate("2014-11-10T23:00:00Z"), 
  "desc" : "Test", 
  "status" : "ok", 
  "playerId" : "ZLkQzaY7DDvwL8sRj",
  "_id" : "kozi9eHcLYa2LbWDG" }
```

My query looks like this:

```
var doc = TestData.findOne({
    playerId: player._id, 
    beginDate: { $gte: new Date(new Date().toISOString()) }, 
    closeDate: { $lte: new Date(new Date().toISOString()) }
});
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. How can I solve it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do the date objects you are trying to filter on have to be `ISODate` instances?

Comment: Yes, it's stored in the DB as `ISODate` instances, I just want to get the document for "today", that is within the range.

Comment: I really don't understand why this does not work.

Comment: what happens if the values you provide to filter with are `ISODate` objects instead of `Date` objects?

Comment: You mean just with: `new Date().toISOString()`?

Comment: I just swapped the operators `$gte` and `$lte` and now I am receiving results. Can you explain why? This does not make sense for me!

Comment: your query is using almost the same date microseconds apart?

Comment: Well, for me it does not really matter. I only need the exact day for my use case (as you can see from `beginDate` and `closeDate`). However, I can't figure out why `$gte` and `$lte` needs to be swapped, it does not make sense. Any idea how I can debug this?

Comment: You need to swap the operators because you're thinking about it backwards.  You want to find the docs where `beginDate` has a value less than or equal to the current time.

Comment: Ah, okay. Now it makes sense. Sorry about that. So it was just a logical problem. Please submit it as answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the logic backwards on the comparisons so you need to swap the `$lte` and `$gte` usage.  You want to find the docs where `beginDate` has a value *less than or equal to* the current time, and a `closeDate` has a value *greater than or equal to* the current time.  You can also just use `new Date()` to get the current time.

```
var doc = TestData.findOne({
    playerId: player._id, 
    beginDate: { $lte: new Date() }, 
    closeDate: { $gte: new Date() }
});
```